# Filter a when passing a parameter and return all when not passing a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I filter the records from the query when I am passing the parameter and return all when the parameter has a null value.

```
SELECT nfv.Company_id, COUNT(1) as NegativeFeedback,SUM(allocated_score) as ScoreSum
FROM dbo.NegativeFeedbackView nfv
WHERE ISNULL(nfv.comp_nature_id,0) = @compNatureId 
GROUP BY nfv.Company_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF/ELSE`:

e.g.

```
IF @compNatureId IS NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT nfv.Company_id, COUNT(1) as NegativeFeedback,SUM(allocated_score) as ScoreSum
    FROM dbo.NegativeFeedbackView nfv
    WHERE ISNULL(nfv.comp_nature_id,0) = @compNatureId 
    GROUP BY nfv.Company_id

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT nfv.Company_id, COUNT(1) as NegativeFeedback,SUM(allocated_score) as ScoreSum
    FROM dbo.NegativeFeedbackView nfv
    GROUP BY nfv.Company_id

END
```

Trying to combine the situations into a single query:

```
SELECT nfv.Company_id, COUNT(1) as NegativeFeedback,SUM(allocated_score) as ScoreSum
FROM dbo.NegativeFeedbackView nfv
WHERE ISNULL(nfv.comp_nature_id,0) = @compNatureId 
OR @compNatureId IS NULL
GROUP BY nfv.Company_id
```

Is likely to yield a sub-optimal plan, and it cannot use any index (if one exists) on `comp_nature_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample proc that takes an optional parameter for filtering.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_MyProc(@FilterParameter AS VARCHAR(100) = NULL)

BEGIN

SELECT nfv.Company_id, COUNT(1) as NegativeFeedback,SUM(allocated_score) as ScoreSum
FROM dbo.NegativeFeedbackView nfv

WHERE
(@compNatureId  IS NULL OR ISNULL(nfv.comp_nature_id,0)= @compNatureId )

GROUP BY nfv.Company_id

END
```